# Convergence of Improper Integrals2

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Test the convergence of $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin x}{x^n}\,dx$$

I tried doing it by comparison test by taking $\phi(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^n}$. Then

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{\phi(x)}=\lim_{n\rightarrow 0}\sin x=0$$ This implies that if $\phi(x)$ converges then $f(x)$ also converges. We can see that $\phi(x)$ converges for $n<1$

But the answer in the book is “$f(x)$ converges for $n<2$”

Have I missed out something?

Comment: For small $x$, $\sin x\sim$ ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem is at $0$ and since 
$$\frac{\sin x}{x^n}\sim_0 \frac{1}{x^{n-1}}$$
so the integral is convergent if and only if $n-1<1\iff n<2$.

Comment: oh ! didn't know we can do that :)

Comment: but will it be wrong if i do it the way i have done ?

Comment: If you use the comparison test: for example if you use that $|\sin x|\leq 1$ you find that the integral is convergent for $n<1$ but in this case you find only a sufficient condition and you missed the case $n=2$.

Comment: @AmanMittal Not so much wrong as incomplete. You've done nothing concerning what the integral does for $n\ge 1$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane one side question, say for $$\int_0^\pi {\sqrt x\over sinx} dx$$ how to proceed with the interval for $c$ to $\pi$ as we cannot use the same logic in this interval

Comment: In this example we have two problems: one at $0$ and the other at $\pi$. Since $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sin x}\sim_0\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ then the integral is convergent at $0$. Now for $\pi$ by change variable $y=\pi-x$ we have  $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sin x}= \frac{\sqrt{\pi-y}}{\sin y}\sim_0 \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{y}$ so the integral is divergent.

Comment: sweet !! Thanks :)

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane another one more or less on the same line :) $$\int_0^1{cosecx\over x^n}$$  I tried the same method of $sinx~x$ but that gives convergent for $n<0$ IS this good ?

Comment: Yes,  it's good.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane But the answer says divergent if $n\ge 1$

Comment: Yes if we say that the integral is convergent for $n<0$ so it's divergent for $n\geq1$ no?:)